# Greater of two columns of a groupby object in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like so (minimum reproducible example):

```
 Search_Term  Exit_Pages      Ratio_x Date_x   Ratio_y Date_y
 hello        /store/catalog  .20     8/30/17  .25     7/30/17
 hello        /store/product  .15     8/30/17  .10     7/30/17
 goodbye      /store/search   .35     8/30/17  .20     7/30/17
 goodbye      /store/product  .25     8/30/17  .40     7/30/17
```

What I am attempting to do is to first group by the Search term and for each search term find the Greater of Ratio_x and Ratio_y (all while keeping all the remaining columns in the dataframe). So the output I would like to see is:

```
Search_Term   Exit_Pages  Ratio_x   Date_x   Ratio_y  Date_y  Highest_Ratio

 hello        /store/catalog  .20     8/30/17  .25     7/30/17  .25
 hello        /store/product  .15     8/30/17  .10     7/30/17
 goodbye      /store/search   .35     8/30/17  .20     7/30/17
 goodbye      /store/product  .25     8/30/17  .40     7/30/17  .40
```

What I have tried to do is to create a groupby Search_Term and apply a Greater of the two columns function using apply as follows (I was afterwards going to join this dataframe to my original to contain the values above, however the error message prevented me from doing that step):

```
def Greater(Merge, maximumA, maximumB):
    a = Merge[maximumA]
    b = Merge[maximumB]
    return max(a,b)

Merger.groupby("Search_Term").apply(Greater, "Ratio_x","Ratio_y")

This gives me the error message: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is 
ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Is there some kind of small modification I can make to make my code work and if so, what would it be? If not, what exactly is the problem and how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a `groupby` + `transform` is what you want?

```
df['Highest_Ratio'] = df.groupby('Search_Term')\
            ['Ratio_x', 'Ratio_y'].transform('max').max(1)

df['Highest_Ratio']

0    0.25
1    0.25
2    0.40
3    0.40
Name: Highest_Ratio, dtype: float64
```

You can perform one more step with `np.where` to get your exact output:

```
m = df['Highest_Ratio'].eq(df['Ratio_x']) | df['Highest_Ratio'].eq(df['Ratio_y'])
df['Highest_Ratio'] = np.where(m, df['Highest_Ratio'], '')

df

  Search_Term      Exit_Pages  Ratio_x   Date_x  Ratio_y   Date_y  \
0       hello  /store/catalog     0.20  8/30/17     0.25  7/30/17   
1       hello  /store/product     0.15  8/30/17     0.10  7/30/17   
2     goodbye   /store/search     0.35  8/30/17     0.20  7/30/17   
3     goodbye  /store/product     0.25  8/30/17     0.40  7/30/17   

  Highest_Ratio  
0          0.25  
1                
2                
3           0.4
```

*Keep in mind it's better to skip this step, since mixing strings and floats isn't the best idea in terms of performance.*

Comment: Reading the question again makes me think this is the solution

Comment: @Bharath I thought your select solution was pretty interesting too (couldn't vote on it since it's been deleted)

Comment: I missed the part of grouping. So thought wasn't a good solution.

Comment: Thank you! That accomplished 95% of what I needed except 1 specific case. When there are multiple cases where that gives equivalent results, it only pulls in the first one. What if I want to pull all of the ones where multiple ratios are highest? Also, can you explain to me the 2nd half of your solution. What is .eq doing?

Comment: @mkheifetz If multiple rows have the same highest value, then the second part of my answer should retain those as well. Basically, the second part is creating a mask and checking whether the value in Highest_Ratio is the same as the value in the corresponding Ratio_* column, and if yes, only those values are kept, masking the others.

Comment: @coldspeed, thanks!! Also, I know I am getting slightly off topic here, any ideas why my initial approach did not work? Is there a small change I can make to make it work? I thought what I was doing was at least logically accurate

Comment: @mkheifetz Truthfully, you're on the right track, but you can't use `max` because that's a simple python function which does not support series as arguments. You'd need to somehow call `pd.Series.max` or `pd.DataFrame.max`.

Comment: @COLDSPEED, hmmm, interesting... Thanks once again!